# Back Test ARIMA model with Exogenous Regressors

Tags: r, validation, time-series

Is there a way to create a holdout/back test sample in following ARIMA model with exogenous regressors. Lets say I want to estimate the following model using the first 50 observations and then evaluate model performance on the remaining 20 observations where the x-variables are pre-populated for all 70 observations. What I really want at the end is a graph that plots actual and fitted values in development period and validation/hold out period (also known as Back Testing in time series)

```
library(TSA)

xreg <- cbind(GNP, Time_Scaled_CO)  # two time series objects 

fit_A <- arima(Charge_Off,order=c(1,1,0),xreg) # Charge_Off is another TS object

plot(Charge_Off,col="red")

lines(predict(fit_A, Data),col="green")  #Data contains Charge_Off, GNP, Time_Scaled_CO
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using the `TSA` package at all, and you don't need to for this problem. Here is some code that should do what you want.

```
library(forecast)
xreg <- cbind(GNP, Time_Scaled_CO)
training <- window(Charge_Off, end=50)
test <- window(Charge_Off, start=51)
fit_A <- Arima(training,order=c(1,1,0),xreg=xreg[1:50,])
fc <- forecast(fit_A, h=20, xreg=xreg[51:70,])
plot(fc)
lines(test, col="red")
accuracy(fc, test)
```

See http://otexts.com/fpp/9/1 for an intro to using R with these models.